# How to get ALL Metadata Filters from Knowledge base

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

As the title, I want to get all of my Knowledge base's Metadata Filters. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get all of my Knowledge base's Metadata Filters.

If you check the QnA Maker REST API V4.0 documentation, you can find that it enables us to downloads the contents of the specified knowledge base by using the [Download knowledge base](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/knowledgebases_download) method, and you can get the collection of all Q-A include **metadata** details in the specified knowledge base.

```
GET https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v4.0/knowledgebases/{kbId}/{environment}/qna
```

*Test result:*

[image]

***Update:***

> I'm using QnAMaker - V3.0.. It also enables to downloads.

Yes, in QnAMaker V3.0 REST API, it also provides the [Download Knowledge Base](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/597029932bcd590e74b648fb/operations/59703d2f5393d704443ee723) method:

```
GET https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/597029932bcd590e74b648fb/operations/59703d2f5393d704443ee723
```

Comment: I'm using QnAMaker - V3.0.. It also enables to downloads. I will try it.. I'm confused about the versions. I know there are some differences. But which one should we use? The higher version, the better?

Comment: I suspect that it might not enable us to use the QnA Maker REST API V4.0 to operate QnAMaker - V3.0, if possible, you can do a test with your QnAMaker service.

Comment: I tested in the web below. I entered my knowledgeBaseID  and Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key .. But it was "401 Access Denied".. What's the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key. https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/597029932bcd590e74b648fb/operations/59703d2f5393d704443ee723/console

Comment: Please check ["Subscription Keys"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/key-management#subscription-keys).